# Delete 2nd to last item array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to delete the 2nd to last item in my array. Using delete puts my indexing out of order?

Getting this using `delete myArr[15];`

[image]

Comment: Describe your question with proper example.

Comment: You could copy the last element's value to the second last, and then delete the last element in the array

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. How do you mean delete it but not put the array out of order? Also, you usually use the "splice" directive for deleting something in array in JavaScript. I didn't even know JavaScript had "delete" keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method instead. This is an example:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr.splice(-2,1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete is a method of an Object and it would delete a key(and so the value) of an Object. In an Array, the key would be the index.

An easy way to do this for Array would be something like:

```
myArr.splice(myArr.length - 2, 1);
```

Or better:

```
myArr = [...myArr.slice(0, - 2), ...myArr.slice(-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete from the second value onwards in an array, isn't it better for you to create a new array with only the first value?

Here is an example:

```js
let anArray = [
  'oneValue',
  'twoValue',
  'threeValue',
  'ecc'
];

console.log('anArray', anArray);

let aNewArray = [anArray[0]];

console.log('aNewArray', aNewArray);
```